# package and distribute DigitalPersona fingerprint applet

Tags: java, security, applet, signed, fingerprint

i need to package and distribute a fingerprint applet i made using java and DigitalPersona One-touch fingerprint  SDK.

Currently the applet has been tested and compiled into jar using Netbeans 8

To distribute the applet, its needs to be package and signed, there seems to be no help on the internet since i have been searching

1. How do I sign the jar files?
2. If I sign the jar files with self generated key locally, will it work in client browser?

After Netbeans compiles the applet to jar, I just copied it to the same directory of the html and called it in the browser like this:

```html
<applet id="fpa"
    code="SensorApplet" archive="FingerprintApplet.jar"
    width="300" height="400">
</applet>
```

I get the following error when the applet runs

```
java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: com/digitalpersona/onetouch/capture/event/DPFPDataListener
```

Comment: *"I get the following error when the applet runs"* SO is a Q&A site rather than a help desk. I put aside that thought long enough to answer a 2nd question that was asked, but please ask separate questions on separate question threads in future. *"..there seems to be no help on the internet since i have been searching"* Unless you hone those search skills, it is unlikely you'll succeed in programming.  The link I put was the top hit for *"How do I sign the jar files?"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem

I was able to get the Applet to work in a Firefox browser, although it pops up three security dialog, which the I needed to only to check "I accept ..." and click run

I simple configure Netbeans to sign the Jar with a self signed cert as it compiled the applet.

I then included all jar library in the archive parameter of the applet like done below

```
<applet id="fpa"
    code="SensorApplet" archive="FingerprintApplet.jar, Jarlib1.jar, Jarlib2.jar, Jarlib3.jar"
    width="300" height="400">
</applet>
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do i sign the jar files?

If I put that exact question into Google, the top hit is [Signing JAR Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html).

> If I sign the jar files with self generated key locally, will it work in client browser?

Short answer, no. Long answer, nope.  But even with a valid code signing certificate, it won't work in Chrome (they've removed all support for applets) and soon(?) won't be supported in IE or FF (at all - same deal as Chrome).

The only hope to get this applet on-screen for general users is to:

1. Sign it with a CA issued code signing certificate.
2. Launch it free floating (not embedded in a browser) using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).